# Rip CD to mp3 using Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3

I would like to rip CDs to MP3. I looked at some pages on the internet on how to do that and they recommended tools like "sound juicer", but since I currently use Rhythmbox as my main music player, I would like to continue using that instead of installing different software.

When I change preferences in Rhythmbox to MP3 (instead of Ogg), it says "Additional software required". When I click the button to download the additional software, I get an error message saying "Unable to find the ID3 tag muxer you were searching for." Now, even though I'm a software developer, I don't have any technical knowledge of the MP3 format or sound-processing software, so that error message sounds foreign to me.

I've seen some similar questions on this site about using Rhythmbox to rip to MP3, but they are very old and probably outdated, and required the installation of specific versions of software that are probably no longer supported. So I'm asking again if there is anything available now in 2023 to make ripping MP3 in Rhythmbox simple. I would have thought that it would be totally straightforward since the old MP3 patent is long expired and there is no reason not to have MP3 ripping as a standard feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In times of Spotify and streaming most developers are not very keen on improving rarely used software features.

However, Rhythmbox uses the gstreamer framework, which itself is fragmented into **nice**, **ugly** and **bad**. You would have to install the package:

```
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

gstreamer has no real interface for setting the quality of your recordings/rippings, so you wont have control over it. That is one reason why sound-juicer is recommended for ripping.

Comment: Why would you choose the "bad" set instead of "good" or "ugly"?

Comment: neither good nor ugly contain the mp3 stuff - that is not free software..